# php json to curl execution

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I received the json output array as

```
 $res =    array(
        'first_name' => 'test',
        'last_name' => 'sam',
        'password' => 'Pass009',
        'email_id' => 'new12@gmail.com',
        'technologies'=>[{
"skill_name": "java",
"experience_in_year": 3,
"experience_in_month": 4
 }, {
"skill_name": "new java",
"experience_in_year": 3,
"experience_in_month": 4
 }],
        'mobile_num'=>'457896315');
```

Here in technology parameter is 2 dimensional array. Bu it is not a string.  So while process  `$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);` It shows an syntax error.

```
php code is

  $curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-KEY: key'));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'save url here');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $res );     
   $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

$result = $buffer;
print_r($buffer);
```

But it shows the syntax error. How to fix this.

Comment: the syntax error because php has a special meaning for the curly brackets '{}' , you can not use these as in javascript or json

Comment: Sorry not clear are you generating that data in PHP?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: This is the input array that we received from android. By using this we process some API calls by receiving this array. In API process we received the error.

Comment: The `'technologies'` part of that array is a JSONString. Is that what is required by the curl target? Or is it a mistake